# PHP modulo quirk

Tags: php, calculator, modulo

I must not know enough about modulo with php. I am getting a strange result.

```
echo (-38 % 26); results in -12
```

Which seems like the right answer to me. Google calculator is returning 14. Which is the right answer for the exercise I'm working on.

What's up with that?

[image: (-38)modulo 26=]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about the subject to make it an answer,  but it's a common thing in programming.   Modulo wants to leave a positive remainder,  it can't make sense of using a negative number.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha also reports the answer as 14. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-38+mod+26

Comment: because modulo wants positive result, then -12 + 26 is 14, but I am not sure if it should be positive number

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519845/modulo-of-a-negative-number

Answer (score 2):

As taken from the PHP manual on [arthimetic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> The result of the modulus operator `%` has the same sign as the dividend
>   — that is, the result of `$a % $b` will have the same sign as `$a`.

Various languages define what sign the remainder will take on differently (Python will use the divisor while PHP uses the dividend for example.) You can read up more about it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: I am more concerned with the numeric value, rather than the sign. I think @kmlnvm came closest to explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
echo ((-38 + 26) % 26);
```

You could make a function which works with positive and negative $a as you intend:

```
function modulo($a, $b) { return ($a + $b) % $b; }
```